# Баг jQuery или браузера?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скажите пожалуйста почему

```
 $("#form").hide()
```

работает , а

```
$("div#form").hide()
```

не работает?

Comment: >Баг jquery или браузера

скорее всего это баг вашего кода

Answer (score 5):

Потому что он **не находит** элемент **div c id="form"**

Возможно вам надо поставить пробел:

```
$("div #form").hide();
```

тогда он будет искать элемент с `id="form"` во всех div-ах

Comment: Никакого пробела не надо все верно там было form#form

Comment: "все верно там было form#form", а почему в вопросе написано div#form?